# Is 'respond them' grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Should it be 'respond them' or does it have to be 'respond *to* them'? I mostly hear people say 'respond to' but there's a part in my textbook with the phrase 'responding them'. I'm non-native so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Hi Egan. Have you tried a dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: What is the full phrase in your textbook?